# What should I do about "pity upvoting"?

Tags: discussion, voting

I've seen many bad posts that I've downvoted, yet someone else gives it an upvote to return the score to 0 (called "pity upvoting").

Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031015/openssl-segfault-in-pem-read) for example. I downvoted it because it didn't seem to show any prior research effort and it didn't provide an MCVE, but then somebody went along and upvoted it.

What should I do about this? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Imagine someone else asking a similar question complaining about a *pity downvote*. In both situation you can do nothing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif What would a "pity downvote" do?

Comment: *I downvoted it because it didn't seem to show any prior research effort, but then somebody went along and upvoted it.* --> they simply don't agree with you.

Comment: *What would a "pity downvote" do?* --> I don't know. You are talking about an upvote you didn't like calling it *pity* someone else may do the same with a downvote.

Comment: There is nothing that can be done about this. People are entitled to vote to cancel out other people's votes if they wish. Indeed, it is not possible to determine that an upvote was made out of pity - perhaps the voter genuinely thought something was a worth upvoting (e.g. they had the same problem and wanted to make it more likely to attract answers).

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Is there an actual “pity” or “sympathy” upvote problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks. I saw that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users can vote based on their discretion. The user who voted on that question might have upvoted it because they had the same question, or perhaps because they saw that the poster had added a clear and concise question, or perhaps they just lost their keys and the cat clicked on upvote instead of downvote, [unlike Tim Post's cat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/311398). We have no idea why they upvoted.

Therefore the only thing that you/others (even moderators) do is to just downvote a particular post, if we feel that it warrants a downvote and not worry about the upvotes which it has. Or, in the worst case, you can just think "why do people upvote this" and move along. There is absolutely nothing else that is required here.

That said if a very bad question gets multiple upvotes in a span of few minutes/seconds, feel free to flag to check for voting irregularities. While a one-off upvote does not indicate voting fraud, multiple upvotes is certainly a strong indicator of it.